# Creating a bitmap (from a set of greyscale values) and saving it to disk - GDI+ generic error

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap, gdi+

Hello I have an array with a bunch of grayscale values

```
var test="...0,222,254,254,254,254,241,198,198,198,198,198,198,198,198,170,52...".Split(',');
```

And I want to create a bitmap with those values

```
int c = 1;
var bmp = new Bitmap(28, 28);          
for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < 28; j++)
{
  bmp.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(test[c]), Convert.ToInt32(test[c]), Convert.ToInt32(test[c])));
  c++;
}
```

However when I try to save it to disk:

```
bmp.Save(@"E:\r\0.jpg",ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

I get the **Generic GDI+ error**

**I have tried**

Checking file permissions

Changing ImageFormat

Cloning the bitmap

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265910/c-convert-image-to-grayscale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm a dumbass, the problem is that I was saving the file to a folder that did not exist, I thought it would be created.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but I just tried this and this works well.

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(28, 28);

        int c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 28; j++)
            {
                bmp.SetPixel(i, j, Color.FromArgb(i, i, i));
            }
        }

        bmp.Save("test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Are you sure the problem is in save?