# Converting different image types to .png format for a WCF Application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, image-conversion, aspose

I need to convert different files formats into .png grayscale (8 or 16 bit) format. I have found tools that can convert documents, PDFs and text docs.

I was looking into  Aspose Imaging for .Net but the API converted grayscaled images are actually larger than the actual files for .jpg, png and tif formats. I want to make them as small as possible, which is part of the requirement.

I have looked into image magik, but our company does not allow open source software in our web service development.

If I use more than one tool for this conversion, will my WCF application get affected? I am sure I will have to use thread safe API's because multiple objects of this application will be running on the server.

Thank you

Comment: check this one if you didn't check already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265910/c-convert-image-to-grayscale and THIS as well: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-convert-a-color-image-to-grayscale

Comment: Those methods are converting them to gryscale, but files are still large! Is there a way to reduce the resolution or bring the file size down? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went with Aspos converter, their product is good but service is not that great. Also looked into snowbound, it wasn't that great.