# Converting System.Drawing Bitmap to Dlib Array2D

Tags: c#, .net, dlib

In this case, a grayscale Array2D for ShapePredictor.

Here is what I am trying, without much success.

```
using DlibDotNet;
using Rectangle = System.Drawing.Rectangle;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class Extension
{
    public static Array2D<byte> ToArray2D(this Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        var bits = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
        var length = bits.Stride * bits.Height;
        var data = new byte[length];

        Marshal.Copy(bits.Scan0, data, 0, length);
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bits);

        var array = new Array2D<byte>(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

        for (var x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
            for (var y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
            {
                var offset = x * 4 + y * bitmap.Width * 4;

                array[x][y] = data[offset];
            }

        return array;
    }
```

I've searched and have not yet found a clear answer.

Comment: You are accessing the data as 32bpp, but trying to put it in an Array2D of `Byte`. You will probably need `Aray2D<Int32>` instead, and read per 4 bytes.

Comment: Notice that I am using offset `offset = x * 4 + y * bitmap.Width` for that same reason.

Comment: Yes, but isn't your return type wrong if it only has one byte in each entry of your 2D array? You'll need a full `Int32` (possibly `UInt32`) for 32bpp pixels. I don't know ShapePredictor, so I don't know what kind of data it expects, but you can't put four bytes of data into one byte.

Comment: The return type is fine. ShapePredictor works with grayscale (8-bit). An `Array2D<byte> array = Dlib.LoadPng<byte>("file.png")` loaded from file works as expected, but what I really need is to be able to convert a Bitmap into Array2D, so that I can work with data that is already loaded in memory.

Comment: You need more than that. You need code to _actually convert your image to grayscale_ too then. You have no such thing in your code; you're accessing it as 32bpp alpha-capable 16 million colour data. Such conversions are better performed _before_ accessing it as bytes.

Comment: For now, I would be satisfied with using just one colour channel, in order to have a working solution. Later, I may write a robust version.

Comment: I think I found your error. You remarked that you are using `offset = x * 4 + y * bitmap.Width`, but in fact _you aren't_. You're multiplying _that_ by 4 _again_. That said, doing multiple multiplications inside the deepest loop is pretty inefficient (and, to be honest, looping over the data per column is pretty weird in itself), so I advise you use the code I provided, which iterates over the image data in the order of the actual image data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted before, you first need to convert your image to grayscale. There are plenty of answers here on StackOverflow to help you with that. I advise the `ColorMatrix` method used in this answer:

[A: Convert an image to grayscale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265990/395685)

I'll be using the `MakeGrayscale3(Bitmap original)` method shown in that answer in my code below.

Typically, images are looped through line by line for processing, so for clarity, you should put your Y loop as outer loop. It also makes the calculation of the data offsets a lot more efficient.

As for the actual data, if the image is grayscale, the R, G and B bytes should all be the same. The order "ARGB" in 32-bit pixel data refers to one `UInt32` value, but those are little-endian, meaning the actual order of the bytes is [B, G, R, A]. This means that in each loop iteration we can just take the first of the four bytes, and it'll be the blue component.

```
public static Array2D<Byte> ToArray2D(this Bitmap bitmap)
{
    Int32 stride;
    Byte[] data;
    // Removes unnecessary getter calls.
    Int32 width = bitmap.Width;
    Int32 height = bitmap.Height;
    // 'using' block to properly dispose temp image.
    using (Bitmap grayImage = MakeGrayscale(bitmap))
    {
        BitmapData bits = grayImage.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
        stride = bits.Stride;
        Int32 length = stride*height;
        data = new Byte[length];
        Marshal.Copy(bits.Scan0, data, 0, length);
        grayImage.UnlockBits(bits);
    }
    // Constructor is (rows, columns), so (height, width)
    Array2D<Byte> array = new Array2D<Byte>(height, width);
    Int32 offset = 0;
    for (Int32 y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        // Offset variable for processing one line
        Int32 curOffset = offset;
        // Get row in advance
        Array2D<Byte>.Row<Byte> curRow = array[y];
        for (Int32 x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            curRow[x] = data[curOffset]; // Should be the Blue component.
            curOffset += 4;
        }
        // Stride is the actual data length of one line. No need to calculate that;
        // not only is it already given by the BitmapData object, but in some situations
        // it may differ from the actual data length. This also saves processing time
        // by avoiding multiplications inside each loop.
        offset += stride;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Your code is more lean, though I noticed a few typos, easily fixed. The conversion still does not work. The main problem is that initialization of Array2D data seems to be undocumented, which is why I am doing this in an array loop. I have seen lots of people asking how to do it, but no definitive answer as of yet.

Comment: @O.Coder I think I found it. The DlibDotNet source code uses `rows` and `columns`, in that order. That means _height_ and _width_. You switched those everywhere. The multidimensional array is, as I already noted, a lot more logical if seen per row, so the access is also `array[y][x]`.

Comment: Haha, oh my. Thanks Nyerguds. That fixed it.

Comment: It also seems every retrieve of a row does a function call, so it's a lot more efficient to retrieve it outside the X loop. I edited the code to show that.