# Get Image monochrome camera Huawei P20

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-camera2, huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to access both the back cameras in the Huawei P20 in real-time. I'm using Unity for now.
I access the different cameras through WebCamTexture.devices, but it can only see the front one and the back RGB camera: the monochrome camera is missing.
I've also checked the android [camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary) reference with no success.

Comment: Why dont you convert your RGB to grayscale?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265910/convert-an-image-to-grayscale

Comment: No, my purpose is to access both cameras togheter. I want to use the stereo camera system