# How can I gray-out a disabled PictureBox used as Button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, picturebox

I'm using Picturebox control as a Button in my app's main dashboard.
The PictureBox has of course an Image that identifies the Button function.

If I use normal Button controls, when disabled, the Buttons' Image it grayed out automatically.
This doesn't happen using a PictureBox.

How can I generated the same *effect* using a Picturebox.

Comment: See the last code block of the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265990/10216583). Better to create a custom PictureBox and override the Paint method to draw the image normally or grayed if the control is disabled. Also you can reduce the opacity (Matrix33) when you create the ColorMatrix  as an additional effect.

Comment: Alternative: [ControlPaint.DrawImageDisabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawimagedisabled?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: I know that but i dont want to use button. I am using PictureBox

Comment: Guys without using button how i can convert image into grayscale which is already in picturebox

Comment: You need to handle the `Paint` event to draw the image according to the value of the `Enabled` property. Maybe a screenshot for the PictureBox with the image helps to understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 9):

**Option 1: CustomControl (PictureBox) + ColorMatrix**

Since you don't want to use a Button, which would gray-out the Image for you when the Control is disabled, you can use a [ColorMatrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix) to change the `PictureBox.BackgroundImage` or (Image) to a gray scale.

The GrayScale matrix you see here uses well-known values to convert an Image to a scaled gray color representation. You can find other interpretations of the same matrix object that may generate different results.
It can be fun to test some or tweak it yourself.

The GrayScale procedure is implemented as an [Extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), since it may come in handy in other situations.
It extends the Image class, adding a `ToGrayScale()` method (you can of course also extend the Bitmap class: you just need to call the Image extension, casting Bitmap to Image, or the other way around, as you prefer).

---

Assuming you have a Custom Control, when the BackgroundImage is changed, you create a GrayScale representation of it and store it.

Then override `OnEnabledChanged` to change the BackgroundImage to either the original or its GrayScale version. A simple check prevents the code from generating a new GrayScale image when the BackgroundImage is changed internally (it's a somewhat simplified method, you should paint the background instead. I'll update it when I can).

[image: GrayScale Matrix PictureBox Image]

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

[DesignerCategory("Code")]
public class ButtonPicture : PictureBox
{
    private Image m_sourceImage = null;
    private Image m_grayImage = null;

    public ButtonPicture() { }

    protected override void OnEnabledChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnEnabledChanged(e);
        this.BackgroundImage = this.Enabled ? m_sourceImage : m_grayImage;
    }
        
    protected override void OnBackgroundImageChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnBackgroundImageChanged(e);
        if (this.BackgroundImage == m_sourceImage || 
            this.BackgroundImage == m_grayImage) return;
        m_sourceImage = this.BackgroundImage;
        m_grayImage = m_sourceImage.ToGrayScale();
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing) {
            m_grayImage.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

The extension method:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

public static class ImageExtensions
{
    static ColorMatrix grayMatrix = new ColorMatrix(new float[][]
    {
        new float[] { .2126f, .2126f, .2126f, 0, 0 },
        new float[] { .7152f, .7152f, .7152f, 0, 0 },
        new float[] { .0722f, .0722f, .0722f, 0, 0 },
        new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 },
        new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 }
    });

    public static Bitmap ToGrayScale(this Image source) {
        var grayImage = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height, source.PixelFormat);
        grayImage.SetResolution(source.HorizontalResolution, source.VerticalResolution);

        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(grayImage))
        using (var attributes = new ImageAttributes()) {
            attributes.SetColorMatrix(grayMatrix);
            g.DrawImage(source, new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height),
                        0, 0, source.Width, source.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);
            return grayImage;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Option 2: ControlPaint + PictureBox.Paint event** (lame)

You can use the [ControlPaint.DrawImageDisabled()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawimagedisabled) method to draw a *disabled*  Bitmap.

- The Graphics object the methods needs is provided by the Control's [PaintEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.painteventargs): subscribe to the `PictureBox.Paint` event and pass the `e.Graphics` object to the method.
- The `Image` argument can be a copy of the `PictureBox.Image` property value.
- The only advantage is that you need quite less code, but the default implementation cannot be controlled and the result is, well, *questionable* (but probably good enough for a generic use).

► Compare the Image on the left, *disabled* using a ColorMatrix, with the Image on the right, *disabled* using the ControlPaint method:

[image: ControlPaint PictureBox disabled Image]

```
private void buttonPicture_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var pict = sender as PictureBox;
    if (pict != null && (!pict.Enabled)) {
        using (var img = new Bitmap(pict.Image, pict.ClientSize)) {
            ControlPaint.DrawImageDisabled(e.Graphics, img, 0, 0, pict.BackColor);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to get the disabled image

```
ToolStripRenderer.CreateDisabledImage(New Bitmap(MyImage))
```

Then you'll be the one changing the image to this one for the disabled button and to the normal one for when it's active

Comment: I think you should have posted this as a comment rather than an answer.