# How to resolve loop error while converting image to gray scale with C#

Tags: c#, image, grayscale

I am trying to do some image processing with C#, I have an image in `pictureBox1` and another one `pictureBox2`. I loaded the original image with no gray scale into the first PictureBox and then put a button event handler to process the Bitmap in the image inside that frame to gray scale and then display the result of the processing into the second PictureBox. When I click the button an exception of type `ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Parameter must be positive and < Width. (Parameter 'x')`. The code inside the button handler is below

```
//get the graysale representation of this image and assign
            Bitmap mymap= new Bitmap(image_path);
            //Rectangle myrect= new Rectangle(0,0,mymap.Width,mymap.Height);
            Bitmap newmap=new Bitmap(mymap.Height,mymap.Width,mymap.PixelFormat);
            Color p;
            for(int y = 0; y < mymap.Height; y++)
            {
                for(int x = 0; x < mymap.Width; x++)
                {
                    p=mymap.GetPixel(x,y);
                    //get the opacity of this color
                    int a=p.A;
                    //get the red component of this pixel
                    int r = p.R;
                    //get the green component of this pixel
                    int g = p.G;
                    //get the blue component of this pixel
                    int b = p.B;
                    //get the average of these colors which is the gray scale
                    int av=(b+g+r)/ 3;
                    //assign to the new Bitmap
                    newmap.SetPixel(x,y,Color.FromArgb(a,av,av,av));
                }
            }
            //assign to pictureBox 2
          pictureBox2.Image=newmap;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note; that's gonna be pretty slow, unlocking and locking for every pixel. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563038/fast-work-with-bitmaps-in-c-sharp

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265990/14171304 - The `ColorMatrix` version.

Comment: @CaiusJard, am clicking the convert button and it does its job in the blink of an eye, what do you mean that is pretty slow?

Comment: The blink of a single eye is a wink and a wink is a hundredth of a minute, which I'd classify as incredibly slow.. even if we speed it up 3-4 times so it's the speed of a 200ms blink it's still pretty slow in computing terms, but if you're happy with it, proceed as you are!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

`Bitmap(mymap.Height,mymap.Width,mymap.PixelFormat);`

To this:

`Bitmap(mymap.Width,mymap.Height,mymap.PixelFormat);`

Bitmap constructor expects parameters: `Width, Height, PixelFormat`

Comment: Yeah, the code needs paying attention, that was the mistake Thank You

Comment: Hey the  code worked but the size of the image in pictureBox2 where the grayscale is is very small, can you check and advise please

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/gfJV5Um

Comment: @KINYUATIMOTHYNJIRU -- Try playing with the `SizeMode` property on the PictureBox

Comment: @did, all modes, `stretch, normal` same result

Comment: found the error, Thanks