# How to convert an rgb image to yuv using c#

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, rgb, yuv

They gave this homework for school. I've been searching for two days but couldn't find it. In my application, The image selected from the computer should be converted from `rgb` to `yuv` and converted to gray color.

I did the conversion to `yuv` below, but there are 2 more missing, so I couldn't convert to `double`, so I made an `int`. The color is not grey.

```
private void btn_piksel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (pct_goruntu.Image == null) return;

    Bitmap goruntu = (Bitmap)pct_goruntu.Image;
    Color ilkPiksel = goruntu.GetPixel(0, 0);

    int genislik = goruntu.Width;
    int yukseklik = goruntu.Height;                     

    Bitmap yeniGoruntu = new Bitmap(genislik, yukseklik);

    for (int sutun = 0; sutun < genislik; sutun++)
    {
        for (int satir = 0; satir < yukseklik; satir++)
        {
            Color piksel = goruntu.GetPixel(sutun, satir);

            double Y = (0.257 * piksel.R) + (0.504 * piksel.G) + (0.098 * piksel.B) + 16;
            double U = (-0.148 * piksel.R) + (-0.291 * piksel.G) + (0.439 * piksel.B) + 128;
            double V = (0.439 * piksel.R) + (-0.368 * piksel.G) + (-0.071 * piksel.B) + 128;

            Color hedefPiksel = Color.FromArgb(piksel.A, (int)Y, (int)U, (int)V);

            yeniGoruntu.SetPixel(sutun, satir, hedefPiksel);
        }
    }

    pct_hedef.Image = yeniGoruntu;

    lbl_kirmizi.Text = "R: " + ilkPiksel.R.ToString();
    lbl_yesil.Text = "G: " + ilkPiksel.B.ToString();
    lbl_mavi.Text = "B: " + ilkPiksel.G.ToString();
}`
```

Comment: Does [this](https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/rgb-to-yuv/) can help convert an RGB image to YUV?

Comment: yes it can help

Comment: There are many YUV formats, and OP's code seems for YUV 420 888 (8 bit, although stored in `double`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the output to be a grayscale image you are only interested in the Luma (Y) component. So you should just use this for all the RGB color channels:

```
 Color.FromArgb(piksel.A, (int)Y, (int)Y, (int)Y);
```

Note that the U and V components are not used, so could be omitted. See also [converting a color image to grayscale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265910/convert-an-image-to-grayscale), and [fast work with bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563038/fast-work-with-bitmaps-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert an RGB image to YUV, you can refer to the following code:

```
public struct RGB
{
    private byte _r;
    private byte _g;
    private byte _b;
    public RGB(byte r, byte g, byte b)
    {
        this._r = r;
        this._g = g;
        this._b = b;
    }
    public byte R
    {
        get { return this._r; }
        set { this._r = value; }
    }
    public byte G
    {
        get { return this._g; }
        set { this._g = value; }
    }
    public byte B
    {
        get { return this._b; }
        set { this._b = value; }
    }
    public bool Equals(RGB rgb)
    {
        return (this.R == rgb.R) && (this.G == rgb.G) && (this.B == rgb.B);
    }
}

public struct YUV
{ 
    private double _y;
    private double _u;
    private double _v;
    public YUV(double y, double u, double v)
    {
        this._y = y;
        this._u = u;
        this._v = v;
    }
    public double Y
    {
        get { return this._y; }
        set { this._y = value; }
    }
    public double U
    {
        get { return this._u; }
        set { this._u = value; }
    }
    public double V
    {
        get { return this._v; }
        set { this._v = value; }
    }
    public bool Equals(YUV yuv)
    {
        return (this.Y == yuv.Y) && (this.U == yuv.U) && (this.V == yuv.V);
    }
}
public static YUV RGBToYUV(RGB rgb)
{
    double y = rgb.R * .299000 + rgb.G * .587000 + rgb.B * .114000;
    double u = rgb.R * -.168736 + rgb.G * -.331264 + rgb.B * .500000 + 128;
    double v = rgb.R * .500000 + rgb.G * -.418688 + rgb.B * -.081312 + 128;
    return new YUV(y, u, v);
}
```

See [this](https://www.programmingalgorithms.com/algorithm/rgb-to-yuv/).